# Find if screen has rounded corners

Tags: android, android-layout

I am looking for a way to determine whether Android device has screen with rounded corners and ideally also the radius.

My usecase is a game that consist of a single fullscreen OpenGL view. It renders some UI elements close to the edges and borders to give as much area as possible to the game itself. But when the screen has rounded corners, they would be partially hidden, so they need to be positioned differently.

Comment: What devices have screens with rounded corners?

Comment: For example Galaxy S8 or Pixel 2 XL.

Comment: Maybe this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration?hl=es#isScreenRound()

Comment: @SemkoToruj This is only for Android Wear devices (with a truly 'round' display)

Comment: Perhaps in an attempt to capitalize on this trend, there are apps that will give you [round corners](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/get-galaxy-s8s-rounded-display-corners-any-android-0176047/) on **any** Android device. Have you thought about that ? You could keep a list of phones and attributes in your app, and on detecting the specific device, deal with it accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update as of 6th June 2019**

> Android officially supports display cutouts on devices running Android
> 9 (API level 28) and higher.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout/

Currently (7th May 2018) you can only check if the physical screen is rounded or not (for Android Wear) using `[isRounded()][1]` method but can not check if *screen corners* are rounded.

I think there are only a few devices with rounded corners out there. So it's better to just check the name of device and adjust your layout accordingly.

There is one popular Android library to get the market name of an Android device. Check here for more information: https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidDeviceNames/

**Usage:**

```
String deviceName = DeviceName.getDeviceName();
```

Hope this workaround will help you temporarily.

Maybe all devices in the future will release with round corner screens (just an assumption).

Comment: Display cutouts do not contain information about rounded corners though. It only provides shapes of notches and such.

Comment: Not only that, but there are "requirements" that state edges can have only a single cutout, which would make the cutout mechanism a bit problematic for describing rounded corners.

Answer (score 7):

Android `S` Developer Preview adds a `RoundedCorner` API, via [`WindowInsets.getRoundedCorner(int position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsets?hl=en#getRoundedCorner(int)). It provides the center point and radius of each rounded corner.

Ref: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features#rounded_corner_apis

Comment: This API does not return the physical rounded corners of the screen, it's an API that allows to set rounded corners to your activity.