# Is there to detect that app is shown on Edge to edge display

Tags: android, android-layout

When I start the app on devices that have an edge to edge display (e.g Samsung S9) app is shown on the whole display (that's not the problem)

My problem is that when the user is in a room with artificial lighting the screen reflects the light and content beneath edge to edge display is much harder to see, read. **This causes bad UX.**

Basically what I want to achieve is

```
if (phone has edges) then layout_margin_start/end="32dp
else layout_margin_start/end="16dp
```

How can I adapt my layouts for edge to edge displays, so the content (text, image) is moved away from edges?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50104945/find-if-screen-has-rounded-corners)? Certainly not the best solution but the only one I could find so far. But it's available from Api-level 23 upwards.

Comment: @Vall0n Am I missing something or this isRouned checks if the device screen has rounded corners. But it would be nice to have something like this

Comment: So far it looks like I could collect devices with rounded corners and then decide which layout to use

Comment: To be honest I don't know. I've never used that. I just thought it could may help you.