# How to find if the device is having rounded corners in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, responsive, rounded-corners

I am looking for a way to determine whether Android device has screen with rounded corners and ideally also the radius.

Comment: It seems it is not possible for native Android too! https://stackoverflow.com/a/50205832/10659482

But you can compare the actual size and the SafeArea size of the screen. Then you can estimate that is rounded if you have padding. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52319524/10659482